# How to add a new categorical column with numbering as per time Interval in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

```
                                      Value
```

2021-07-15 00:00:00  10

2021-07-15 06:00:00 10

2021-07-15 12:00:00 10

2021-07-15 18:00:00 10

2021-07-16 00:00:00 20

2021-07-16 06:00:00 10

2021-07-16 12:00:00 10

2021-07-16 18:00:00 20

I want to add a column such that when it

00:00:00 1

06:00:00 2

12:00:00 3

18:00:00 4

Eventually, I want something like this

```
                Value  Number
```

2021-07-15 00:00:00  10     1

2021-07-15 06:00:00 10      2

2021-07-15 12:00:00 10      3

2021-07-15 18:00:00 10      4

2021-07-16 00:00:00 20      1

2021-07-16 06:00:00 10      2

2021-07-16 12:00:00 10      3

2021-07-16 18:00:00 20       4

and so on

I want that Numbering column such that whenever it's 00:00:00 time it always says 1, whenever it's 06:00:00 time it always says 2, whenever it's 12:00:00 time it always says 3, whenever it's 18:00:00 time it always says 4. In this way, I will have a categorical column having only 1,2,3,4 values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert to datetime and `.dt.time` to extract the time. You can use `pd.factorize` for 1,2,3,4 categories.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '2021-07-15 00:00:00 0.48',
    '2021-07-15 06:00:00 80.00',
    '2021-07-15 12:00:00 6.10',
    '2021-07-15 18:00:00 1400.00',
    '2021-07-16 00:00:00 1400.00'
}, columns=['value'])
df
#                          value
# 0     2021-07-15 00:00:00 0.48
# 1    2021-07-15 06:00:00 80.00
# 2     2021-07-15 12:00:00 6.10
# 3  2021-07-16 00:00:00 1400.00
# 4  2021-07-15 18:00:00 1400.00

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'].str[:19])
df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
df['index'], _ = pd.factorize(df['time'])
df['index'] += 1
df
#                          value                date      time  index
# 0     2021-07-15 00:00:00 0.48 2021-07-15 00:00:00  00:00:00      1
# 1    2021-07-15 06:00:00 80.00 2021-07-15 06:00:00  06:00:00      2
# 2     2021-07-15 12:00:00 6.10 2021-07-15 12:00:00  12:00:00      3
# 4  2021-07-15 18:00:00 1400.00 2021-07-15 18:00:00  18:00:00      4
# 3  2021-07-16 00:00:00 1400.00 2021-07-16 00:00:00  00:00:00      1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But I want that Numbering column such that whenever it's 00:00:00 time it always says 1, whenever it's 06:00:00 time it always says 2, whenever it's 12:00:00 time it always says 3, whenever it's 18:00:00 time it always says 4. In this way, I will have  a categorical column having only 1,2,3,4 values

Comment: @RavikantPandey I updated. please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, new here, so I don't have enough rep to comment. But @Keiku's solution is closer than you realise. If you replace .time by .hour, you get the hour of the day. Divide that by 6 to get 0-3 categories for 0:00 to 18:00. If you must have them in the range 1-4 specifically, simply add 1.

To borrow @Keiku's example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '2021-07-15 00:00:00 0.48',
    '2021-07-15 06:00:00 80.00',
    '2021-07-15 12:00:00 6.10',
    '2021-07-15 18:00:00 1400.00',
    '2021-07-16 00:00:00 1400.00'
    }, columns=['value'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'].str[:19])
df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)
df['category'] = df['date'].dt.hour / 6  # + 1 if you want this to be 1-4
```